# calculating tilting angle using labview, cdaq and imu

Tags: accelerometer, labview, gyroscope

i would like to ask how to calculate tilting angle accurately using 
IMU unit SN-IMU5D-LC
http://www.cytron.com.my/viewProduct.php?pcode=SN-IMU5D-LC
and cDAQ 9188 and labview 
how to implement kalman filter or complementary 
thanks

Comment: Without any code or examples of your setup it's pretty hard to answer that question. Also try to split it up in relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I would take:

1. Figure out how to read out the tilt using a simple voltmeter since that's how you'll be using the DAQ. If you need help with this that's more of a EE question.
2. Read the voltage into LabVIEW using the cDAQ 9188. This can be easily configured using the NI DAQmx library and there's plenty of LabVIEW examples.
3. There should also be ample examples for implementing the Kalman filter as noted here:
   http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Accelerometer-Gyro-Kalman-Filter/td-p/815001

(to access LabVIEW examples go to Help >> Find Examples)